# Windows 2008 64 bit OS Retrieving the COM class factory failed

Tags: asp.net

**I am doing excel automation at Server Side through my website .The code uses excel interop dlls. The server I am deploying is 64 bit windows 2008 . I tried most of the options I researched in web but still getting below message.**

Options tried :
1)  Configured IIS 7 Aplication pool to accept 32 bit app -failed
2)  Rebuild the code with Target platform as X86 - failed
3)  Created desktop folders under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop - failed

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: is excel installed on the machine?

Comment: don't do Excel automation on server side, it's not supported